# Add two maps in Presto

Tags: presto

My data is as mentioned below

```
customer_id   usage_month  usage_by_product         usage
1             June         {"A":50, "B":50}         100
1             July         {"A":50, "B":10, "C":20} 80
1             Aug          {"A":50, "D":500}        550
1             Sep          {"C" :30}                30
```

I want to write a query that aggregates the total usage for the complete year

```
customer_id   usage_by_product    usage
 1            {"A": 150, "B":60   760
               "C": 50, "D":500}
```

Is it possible to do this kind of aggregation on maps in Athena (Presto)?

Answer (score 6):

You can split your map into individual key/value pairs with `map_entries` + `UNNEST`. Then, it's a matter of summing and aggregating values back into a `map`.

For example:

```
WITH input AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (1, map(array['a', 'c'], array[50, 42])), 
        (1, map(array['a', 'b'], array[50, 18]))
    ) t(customer_id, m)
),
sum_by_map_key AS (
    SELECT customer_id, k, sum(v) AS s
    FROM input
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(map_entries(m)) AS u(k, v)
    GROUP BY customer_id, k
)
SELECT customer_id, map_agg(k, s)
FROM sum_by_map_key
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Outputs:

```
 customer_id |        _col1
-------------+---------------------
           1 | {a=100, b=18, c=42}
(1 row)
```

Note:
to just add two maps like this, you could use [`map_zip_with`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_zip_with). However, to use it when aggregating over multiple rows you would probably need to aggregate all the maps values into single `array` and run array reduction on it. Aggregating all the maps into single `array(map)` may or may not work, depending on the size of these arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I did explore map_zip_with, in the documentation 
"Merges the two given maps into a single map by applying function to the pair of values with the same key. For keys only presented in one map, NULL will be passed as the value for the missing key.". So when I'm trying to add the values it adds null to a int value, when the same key is not present in both the maps ?

Comment: And to my surprise athena has an older version of Presto (0.172), which doesn't support map_with_zip, map_entries and map_agg.

Comment: For `map_zip_with` you would use `coalesce(v1, 0) + coalesce(v2, 0)` to sum values to handle missing keys properly.

I didn't know these functions don't exist in Athena. 0.172 is really old already.
Unless you query only rarely (i.e. when Athena cost model works best), I would suggest https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/ or EMR.

Answer (score 0):

Newer version of presto supports the aggregation function map_union_sum